# How to use jQuery UI draggable and droppable in specific position in a table?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I want to drag some items in a table and drop them on other table row that have specific number! (So I don't want jquery-UI-sortable) and here is my work:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9pn29Lq/5/)

```
<table width="320px">
<tbody>
    <tr style="line-height:30px">
        <td width="10%">Pos1</td>
        <td width="90%" rowspan="5">
            <div class="dragable-object" >Item 1</div>
            <div class="dragable-object" >Item 2</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr style="line-height:30px"><td class="position" width="10%">Pos2</td>
    <tr style="line-height:30px"><td class="position" width="10%">Pos3</td>
    <tr style="line-height:30px"><td class="position" width="10%">Pos4</td>
    <tr style="line-height:30px"><td class="position" width="10%">Pos5</td>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(".dragable-object").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"        
});

$(".position").droppable();
</script>
```

How should I do that?

Comment: I tried changing your code, I am able to drag and drop fine.
The only change I did is changing width to accommodate draggable content.
Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mL338128/40/

Comment: Thanks , but I want to drop items in front of Positions! how should I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by infront of positions?
Inside droppable section only or anything else?

Comment: inside <td class='postion'>

Comment: Currently also, same thing is happening. You are placing content inside <td class='position'> only. You just see it overlapping because of less space in td.position.
But if you want that element should become one of the columns, do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/mL338128/47/

Comment: How could I put draggable elements inside <tr> and put them in a row with <td class='position'>!?

Comment: Check this now:
http://jsfiddle.net/mL338128/48/

If it is ok, I will update it as an answer.
Also few suggestions, you are using inline style at multiple places.Don't do it. Use external or internal CSS and start using classes.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I want move my items only vertical and my rows height (tr tags) should not be changed! Actually it's a data center rack simulation!!

Comment: This can also be done but would you like to try something now seeing the above fiddles? I am sure what you want now should not be that difficult to achieve.

Comment: Your code moves my div tag inner texts! I should move all my div content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143094/discussion-between-nitesh-and-amir-zaghari).

Answer (score 0):

You can  try this,

```
$(function() {
    $(".dragable-object").draggable({
        revert: "invalid", 
        cancel: "a.ui-icon",
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "pointer"
    });
    $( ".position" ).droppable({
        tolerance: "touch",
        accept: ".dragable-object",
        classes: {"ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-highlight"},
        drop: function (event, ui) {
           var sss="<tr style='line-height:30px'><td class='position' width='50%'>";
           sss +=(ui.draggable.context.innerText);
           sss +="</td>";
           $("tbody").append(sss);
        }
   });
});
```

Use following link: http://jsfiddle.net/mL338128/46/

Comment: I need to move my items only in droppable elements (<td class="position" )

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is an issue with your jQuery or jQuery UI library. Tested with jQuery 3.1.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fyxjLh3y/6/

**HTML**

```
<table width="320px">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="line-height:30px">
      <td width="10%">Pos1</td>
      <td width="90%" rowspan="5">
        <div class="dragable-object">Item 1</div>
        <div class="dragable-object">Item 2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="line-height:30px">
      <td class="position" width="10%">Pos2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="line-height:30px">
      <td class="position" width="10%">Pos3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="line-height:30px">
      <td class="position" width="10%">Pos4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="line-height:30px">
      <td class="position" width="10%">Pos5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dragable-object {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 10em;
}

.highlight {
  border-color: #000;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".dragable-object").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    containment: "table"
  });

  $(".position").droppable({
    accept: "div",
    tolerance: "touch",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "highlight"
    },
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      ui.draggable.attr("style", "");
      $(this).append(ui.draggable);
      $(this).find(".dragable-object").draggable("destroy");
    }
  });
});
```